# Combine two Taylor expansions (Lindeberg CLT)

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, taylor-expansion, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

I am currently reading a proof of Lindeberg-Feller CLT from this [article](http://math.iisc.ac.in/%7Emanju/Old/ProbTheory/Notes/16-18%20CLT.pdf). Here's the problem I encountered:

[image]

I can understand the idea of using $x^3$ term to estimate small $x$ and use $x^2$ to estimate large $x$. But the problem is, why does the last equality hold? I try to do some calculations and cannot find an answer.

Also, most proof of the CLT use the estimation like this
[image]

and I can't understand why this holds either.

Comment: @Bernard Found that the question isn't precise, the equation I meant is the last one (one with indicator function), sorry.

Comment: I see – I misunderstood your question. No idea for the formula with indicator, sorry.